# HTML Button gets executed before pressed

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

0

I have a html template which contains a button when u press the button it executes a function in views.py which i will list:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def button(request):

    return render(request, 'home.html')

def output(request):
    def trade_spider(max_pages):
        dat = ''
        page = 1
        while(page <= max_pages):
            search = 'Ipad'
            url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=' + search + '&_sacat=0&_pgn=' + str(page)
            src = requests.get(url)
            text = src.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="html.parser")
            for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 's-item__link'}):
                href = link.get('href')
                title = link.string
                if(title == None):
                    title = "Sorry the title was unavailable however you can check the price."
                price = get_item_price(href)
                dat += href + '\n' + title + '\n' + price
                page+=1
                return dat


    def get_item_price(item_url):
        src = requests.get(item_url)
        text = src.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="html.parser")
        for item_price in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'notranslate'}):
                price = item_price.string
                return price

    data = trade_spider(1)
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'data': data})
```

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Python button script
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Execute Script</button> <hr>
        {% if data %}

        {{data | safe}}

        {% endif %}

        </body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine however when i run the page it diplays the button AND the output which i dont want i want it to show the output after i press the button. The python version is 3.6.0 django=2.1 it is in a virtualenv using pipenv and thats about all the details i have. If you need the code of another file just comment also incase you need the directory and the files in it here is a tree:

```
C:.
│   Pipfile
│   Pipfile.lock
│
└───comparison
    │   db.sqlite3
    │   manage.py
    │
    ├───comparison
    │       settings.py
    │       urls.py
    │       wsgi.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    └───register
        │   admin.py
        │   apps.py
        │   models.py
        │   tests.py
        │   views.py
        │   __init__.py
        │
        ├───migrations
        │       __init__.py
        │
        └───templates
                home.html
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from register.views import output

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', output)
]
```

Comment: Well what do you expect? You call the function, it displays the result. As far as I can tell the button is never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lonely button by itself is not going to do anything.

To make the button clickable, you wrap the button inside a `<form>` element and give the form an `action` with the page you want to send the form submission to. Also give it the `method` `post`. Also give the button the `type` of `submit` and a value. Something like this:

```html
<form name="myform" method="post" action="/register/">
  <button type="submit" value="execute">Execute Script</button>
</form>
```

Then in your Django view, you only print the output if the button has been clicked.
You can check this by looking if the request method is post, and if the submit button has been submitted.

Something like this:

```py
def output(request):

    data = False #Setting the default to false makes it easy to check for it in your template.
    submitbutton= request.POST.get('execute') #Looking for the value of the button in the POST variables.

    if submitbutton:
    # Only if the button has been clicked, do we execute the code to get the output.
        def trade_spider(max_pages):
            dat = ''
            page = 1
            while(page <= max_pages):
                search = 'Ipad'
                url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=' + search + '&_sacat=0&_pgn=' + str(page)
                src = requests.get(url)
                text = src.text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="html.parser")
                for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 's-item__link'}):
                    href = link.get('href')
                    title = link.string
                    if(title == None):
                        title = "Sorry the title was unavailable however you can check the price."
                    price = get_item_price(href)
                    dat += href + '\n' + title + '\n' + price
                    page+=1
                    return dat


        def get_item_price(item_url):
            src = requests.get(item_url)
            text = src.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="html.parser")
            for item_price in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'notranslate'}):
                price = item_price.string
                return price

        data = trade_spider(1)
    # We still return the same thing, but unless the button has been clicked, the value of data will remain False
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'data': data})
```

Now the `{% if data %}` in your template will only return `True` if the button was clicked, so it will not try to display anything if it wasn't.